# How many side-car proxy is too much in a pod

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, containers, cloud, distributed-system

I am currently studying distributed systems and have seen that many businesses relies on side-car proxy pattern for their services. For example, I know a company that uses an nginx proxy for authentication of their services and roles and permissions instead of including this business logic within their services.

Another one makes use of a cloud-sql-proxy on GKE to use the Cloud SQL offering that comes on google cloud. So on top of deploying their services in a container which runs in a pod, they is a proxy just for communicating with the database.

There is also istio which is a service mesh solution which can be deployed as a side-car proxy in a pod.

**I am pretty sure there are other commonly know use-cases where this pattern is used but at some point how much is too much side-car proxy? How heavy is it on the pod running it and what are the complexity that comes with using 2, 3, or even 4 side car proxys on top of your service container?**

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to define what really you need and continue your research based on this, since this topic is too broad and doesn't have one correct answer.

Due to this, I decided to post a community wiki answer. Feel free to expand it.

There can be various reasons for running some containers in one pod. According to [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#workload-resources-for-managing-pods):

> A Pod can encapsulate an application composed of multiple co-located
> containers that are tightly coupled and need to share resources. These
> co-located containers form a single cohesive unit of service—for
> example, one container serving data stored in a shared volume to the
> public, while a separate  *sidecar*  container refreshes or updates
> those files. The Pod wraps these containers, storage resources, and an
> ephemeral network identity together as a single unit.

In its simplest form, a sidecar container can be used to add functionality to a primary application that might otherwise be difficult to improve.

**Advantages of using sidecar containers**

- sidecar container is independent from its primary application in terms of runtime environment and programming language;
- no significant latency during communication between primary application and sidecar container;
- the sidecar pattern entails designing modular containers. The modular container can be plugged in more than one place with minimal modifications, since you don't need to write configuration code inside each application.

**Notes regarding usage of sidecar containers**

- consider making a small sidecar container that doesn't consume much resources. The strong point of a sidecar containers lies in their ability to be small and pluggable. If sidecar container logic is getting more complex and/or becoming more tightly coupled with the main application container, it may better be integrated with the main application’s code instead.
- to ensure that any number of sidecar containers can works successfully with main application its necessary to sum up all the resources/request limits while defining resource limits for the pod, because all the containers will run in parallel. Whole functionality works only if both types of containers are running successfully and most of the time these sidecar containers are simple and small that consume fewer resources than the main container.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor yes it does! but created even more questions that I need to research one

Comment: +1 thank you very much for your in depth answer. It was a theoritical question since I am not using any side-car containers in any project. I am simply interested in this architectural pattern and the side effect of such approach given that most cloud technologies are relying on this pattern to "inject" fonctionalities to their services without touching application code (functionalities such as metrics, authentication, circuit breaker, service discovery)

Comment: Do you know if containers within the same pod comunicate "over the network" ?
Is the latency of deserializing and serilizing those request and sending them between containers is increased ?

For example, I am thinking of istio service mesh which uses side car containers to enable their services. If I have 30 services all deployed with an istio side car, then for each request between services they are doubled due to the addition of istio service mesh. I wonder how impacted is the performance

Comment: anyhow, I have plenty or research to do to answer my own questions

Comment: How is your research progressing? If you have unanswered questions it would be better to ask as a separate question.